# How to pass imediate values in Smali Assembly language?

Tags: java, android, assembly, bytecode, smali

I have a smali code in which I want to inject a sleep function right at the beginning. To do so, I've created an app that just sleeps, generated its smali and copied into an app as the first instructions of the `onCreate` method and worked perfectly, the generated code was:

```
.locals 2
const-wide/16 v0, 0x2710

:try_start_0
invoke-static {v0, v1}, Ljava/lang/Thread;->sleep(J)V
:try_end_0
.catch Ljava/lang/InterruptedException; {:try_start_0 .. :try_end_0} :catch_0

:catch_0
//code continues here
```

I've tested in an app and it worked, really sleept for `0x2710` milisecconds (10 seconds). Notice that I had to change the `locals` value to inject the new variable. Now, I want to add this same piece of code into another app but when I run this app with this code I got the error:

> 10-04 22:53:50.709  4396  4396 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class com.sulctue.beaiasa.hcoisis: void com.sulctue.beaiasa.hcoisis.onCreate() failed to verify: void com.sulctue.beaiasa.hcoisis.onCreate(): [0x2] Rejecting invocation, long or double parameter at index 0 is not a pair: 9 + 1. (declaration of 'com.sulctue.beaiasa.hcoisis' appears in /data/app/com.paranbijuv.aijuy-bovbnI4hv2jswty95nHE9A==/base.apk)
>   10-04 22:53:50.709  4396  4396 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
>   
> 10-04 22:53:50.709  4396  4396 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1102)
>   
> 10-04 22:53:50.709  4396  4396 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>   
> 10-04 22:53:50.709  4396  4396 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:983)
>   
> 10-04 22:53:50.709  4396  4396 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5715)
>   
> 10-04 22:53:50.709  4396  4396 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
>   
> 10-04 22:53:50.709  4396  4396 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1656)
>   
> 10-04 22:53:50.709  4396  4396 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>   
> 10-04 22:53:50.709  4396  4396 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>   
> 10-04 22:53:50.709  4396  4396 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
>   
> 10-04 22:53:50.709  4396  4396 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   
> 10-04 22:53:50.709  4396  4396 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>   
> 10-04 22:53:50.709  4396  4396 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
>   
> 10-04 22:53:53.470  1656  1907 I ActivityManager: Killing 4396:com.paranbijuv.aijuy/u0a79 (adj 900): crash

So, how do I just call:

```
invoke-static {v0, v1}, Ljava/lang/Thread;->sleep(J)V
```

with the imediate value of `0x2710` instead of the variable `v0`? I've tried just calling `invoke-static {0x2710, v1} (...)` but failed with the same error message as above.

Comment: Could you please post the exact code that you are getting the verification error for?

Comment: The error message is literally the same on both cases: `"Rejecting invocation, long or double parameter at index 0 is not a pair: 9 + 1"`. Both verified by the logcat

Comment: I've just posted the code here at https://pastebin.com/9xzyj0v3 so it doesn't overwhelm my question with 1000 lines of code...

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the posted code. A couple things to try to narrow down the issue: try disassembling and reassembling the app with no modifications and see if it works. Then do the same with your test app.

Comment: I disassembled and reassembled making no modifications at all, I noticed that the reassemble worked normally but had a different `sha256` hash than the original

Comment: Which app are you using? I could try to do it myself and see if it works for me when I have time.

Comment: https://contagiominidump.blogspot.com/2016/07/marcher-overlay-android-trojan.html, the first apk with sha256sum equals to "fafaebe042ba9c59b2c3f65f43774cdb5369f838469e133a7c26e824f6d20cc6"

Comment: Should this be tagged [tag:java-bytecode-asm]?  This isn't assembly for a real CPU, but I don't know if this is really java-bytecode-asm or some other kind of Java-related bytecode.  If it's the internal representation for some specific JVM, not then I guess not.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to pass constant values directly to a function in Dex bytecode. Everything has to be stored in a register first.

It is difficult to tell what you did wrong based only on the error message, but my guess is that the locals you injected are causing problems with the code that follows your injected code. Perhaps you are accidentally overwriting a method parameter that the code uses. Could you please post the exact code that you are getting the verification error for?

P.S. If you tried to run `invoke-static {0x2710, v1}`, you shouldn't "get the exact same error as above" because that code won't even assemble. You should have gotten a smali error, so it is possible that the apk you are running isn't the result of assembling the code you think it is. You should double check your tool setup and make sure you're installing and running the right apk.